# In Z3: how if then else based conditions be formulated (based on evaluations of variables)?

Tags: z3, c-api

I'm new to Z3 and still couldn't find how I can express conditional new assignments based on the different possible evaluations. In If-then-else example in 
https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c/test_capi.c#L1846
I still need to make the assignment to true or false, and when I want to make it true or false based on possible evaluations of another variable. How can I do this?

In the [evaluation example](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/blob/master/examples/c/test_capi.c#L1461) I want the value calculated to be used to affect the still not evaluated values that are going to be checked by assertion later. So if this is the way how I can return back the model UN-evaluated with the new (evaluation based) conditions to the context again? i.e. I want to do composite conditions without final evaluations. Is that possible?

Comment: Your problem description is very hard to understand. Are you saying that the fact that the ite_example makes a reference to the function Z3_mk_false is in some way undesirable?

Comment: I want this "condition = Z3_mk_false" to be called only when some condition happens (for example: in the case some variable takes certain value) so that I can use "condition = Z3_mk_true" in other cases (where the variable takes other values for example).

Comment: See my answer below. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line from `ite_example()`:

```
ite  = Z3_mk_ite(ctx, f, one, zero)
```

creates an expression that will evaluate to whatever the (symbolic) term `one` evaluates to, if `f` evaluates to true, or alternatively to whatever `zero` evaluates to, if `f` evalautes to false. In `ite_example`, `f` always evaluates to `false`, but it may be any other (symbolic) term of Boolean sort.

For example,

```
x = mk_int_var(ctx, "x"); 
y = mk_int_var(ctx, "y"); 
x_eq_y = Z3_mk_eq(ctx, x, y);
```

will create a term called `x_eq_y`, representing "x = y", which is of Boolean sort.

Comment: I tried that, but when I used a Boolean sort (for f) I got this warning message "warning: invalid conversion from ‘Z3_bool {aka int}’ to ‘Z3_ast {aka _Z3_ast*}’". And when I suppressed it by -fpermissive I got a segmentation fault.

Comment: Let's call "sort" the "type". You can't pass a "type" into Z3_mk_ite, it needs an "expression", for example a "variable" (which can be of some "type")

Comment: I added a further example, does that clarify things?